# autosave in osx lion

Tags: macos

Will it be possible to disable the Auto Save feature in OS X Lion?

Comment: Please bear in mind that we generally don't talk about "future" things because I may say now: "No it's not possible at the moment" and the next developer's preview changes that, rendering this question (and its answers) kind of useless for new users looking for clues about how to disable or enable the aforementioned feature. In any case, there's no setting so far that allows you to disable this feature and/or an in-app setting to override it. (Developer's Preview 2).

Comment: This question might better be posed now to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Since Lion testers are under a non-disclosure agreement (NDA) it may be difficult to get a definitive answer on this here.  From my reading of what has been released so far, and reading between the lines to Apples intent on bringing iOS (and in particular the iPad) functionality/experience to the Desktop, I would say that the Applications written for Lion will use that feature, and it will not be able to be turned off.

I say this because I think that the autosave and version system will be deep in the guts of the OS and once an application is written to use this feature, it won't be an option.

That's not to say that people won't find a way around it.